# Document-Rendering in Java

Tags: java, image, ms-word, rendering

I want to render MSWord, PDF, HTML, etc to an image (e.g. TIFF) from server-side Java.

Most available products are shareware printer drivers, and so not suited to a commercial server app: I'd like the library which is robust, well-supported, performant, and concurrent.

Any suggestions for open-source or commercial libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to these:

- [A good library for converting PDF to TIFF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356550/a-good-library-for-converting-pdf-to-tiff);
- [Export PDF pages to a series of images in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550129/export-pdf-pages-to-a-series-of-images-in-java); and
- [Java library for converting Word documents to PDFs or images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437394/java-library-for-converting-word-documents-to-pdfs-or-images) .

And if you didn't find them in a search don't feel bad, you probably just used the SO search instead of googling for "site:stackoverflow.com convert pdf image java" (etc).

Comment: Thanks, yes, I used the SO search.

Still, those answers don't address my question: How to render MSWord (or HTML) to an image, e.g., TIFF. 

They do give ideas for PDF-to-image, but I was hoping for a solution for these other formats -- and preferably the same solution covering them all.

Comment: Thanks, that's good. It would be best to have a universal solution: HTML, PDF, Word, plaintext, and all other formats.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that somewhere in this API, [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/), you'll be able to render a PDF to an image. For HTML you may consider [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) (but the project looks deadish). Shame that [JWebPane](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ixmal/archive/2008/05/introducing_jwe.html) isn't ready yet.

For MSWord ... no clue.