# Open a PDf file in android

Tags: android, pdf, resources

I am going to write an android app, which will contain a PDF file (included with in the application). My task is, when i click a button , pdf file should open . PDf file is placed in assets/raw (not sure where to place ).

Can any one help on this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Open the PDF and display it on the phone?

Comment: thanks turbo for quick response, But i do not know how to open a pdf file which is placed in raw/assests folder

Comment: Open it and do what with it though, simply display it?  I don't think you really even do anything else, but your question does not make it clear.  See the linked possible duplicate and see if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can open pdf via webview and google docs.
You should use

```
WebView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=www.site.com/file.pdf");
```

Comment: Since the PDF is not an online resource, this will become rather complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [PDF Renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6118652/1188208) to convert the file to a Bitmap. Otherwise, you would have to use another application to open the file, or the option that Walter gave you. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4895827/1188208) is an example using a different library for rendering a PDF using Java.