# How to crop and convert a specific section of a PDF page into image?

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdfbox

I have a pdf containing text and images. I need to crop a specific section from every PDF page and convert it into image. Please suggest me how  can I do it. Remember I dont want to convert entire page into image. I need to crop some part from the page and then convert it into image.

Comment: already answered 
please refer to link 

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886042/pdf-to-image-using-java>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356550/a-good-library-for-converting-pdf-to-tiff

Comment: I dont want to convert entire pdfpage into an image i need to convert a specific section into image.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Snipping Tool in Win7 to cut the section of the screen you need and save it as an image.

Refer to the following article: [Click](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screen-shots)

Comment: I have 1000 pdfs to be processed and i need to write a program.

Answer (score 0):

If solutions above (Ghostscript) are OK and the only problem is to specify page region, try

```
gs -sDEVICE=png16m -o out.png -dFIXEDMEDIA \
   -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=100 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=200 \
   -c '<</PageOffset [-300 400]>>setpagedevice' \
   -f in.pdf
```

Sizes are in 1/72" points. Here: offset 300 from left, 400 from bottom (i.e. from lower left corner) and get 100x200 region. Note: `[-300 400]`are for images, but `[-300 -400]` are for display and high level (e.g. pdfwrite) devices. I.e. shifting down is positive and negative, respectively.